# How to stop MathJax in rendering from other page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax

I have a situation that I noticed that everytime I load a page that contain `mathjax` and when I go to other page with another mathjax, I will wait for almost 2 minutes to load. My opinion is that mathjax load first all the formula from the other page before rendering the formula in the current page...

I don't really know what I caused because it is only my opinion but that was I noticed.

Im using `angularJS` and here is my code in directives:

```
app.directive("mathjaxBind", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs",
            function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch($attrs.mathjaxBind, function (texExpression) {
                    $element.html(texExpression);
                    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, $element[0]]);
                });
            }]
    };
});
```

What might be the cause of this problem? If I'm correct with my opinion, how to stop `mathjax` in rendering if it I'm now in the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to update your mathjax every load of your formula. What I did is that i initials update every repeat.

I do it like this..

```
<a mathjax-bind="competency.competencyDescription" data-ng-init="UpdateMathJax()">

$scope.UpdateMathJax = function () {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
    };
```

I hope it will help you.